# Javascript Fetch doesnt have Server Message

Tags: javascript, php

### This is my javscript code:

```
 await fetch("...",
 {
     method: "POST",
     body: formData,
     headers: { "X-CSRF-Token": csrfToken}
 }).then( (res) => {
       console.log(res);
    })
```

### Console.log() output:

[image]

### This is my PHP code:

```
return new Response(null, HttpSuccessCode::$OK, "Test"); 
//null = ressource, HTTPSuccessCode::$OK = HTTPStatusCode, "Test" = message
```

[image]

**Problem: Javascript .Then() response doesnt have the Message attribute, but i dont know why**

Comment: `res` hasn't yet "processed" the body, you need to use one of res.text, res.json, res.blob etc to "process" the body - as documented in *[documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)*

Comment: Where in your PHP do you actually echo anything back to the client? All we see is one line of code without any context.

Comment: @Adyson i return for testing a Response, other code is not important to this question